# Getting imfilter to work with gpuarrays

Tags: matlab

I am trying to speed up some code bounded by the performance of imfilter, so I installed the Parallel Computing Toolbox and tested the imfilter on a gpu array

```
EDU>> imfilter(gpuArray([0]), [1])
Error using imfilter
Expected input number 1, A, to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was parallel.gpu.GPUArray.

Error in imfilter>parse_inputs (line 359)
validateattributes(a,{'numeric' 'logical'},{'nonsparse'},mfilename,'A',1);

Error in imfilter (line 131)
[a,h,boundary,flags] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

Running methods I get

```
EDU>> methods('parallel.gpu.GPUArray')

Methods for class parallel.gpu.GPUArray:

GPUArray              display               isequaln              rem                   
abs                   divergence            isequalwithequalnans  repmat                
acos                  dot                   isfinite              reshape               
acosh                 double                isinf                 ribbon                
acot                  eig                   islogical             rose                  
acoth                 end                   isnan                 round                 
acsc                  eps                   isocaps               scatter3              
acsch                 eq                    isocolors             sec                   
all                   erf                   isonormals            sech                  
and                   erfc                  isosurface            semilogx              
any                   erfcinv               isreal                semilogy              
area                  erfcx                 issorted              shiftdim              
arrayfun              erfinv                ldivide               shrinkfaces           
asec                  errorbar              le                    sign                  
asech                 existsOnGPU           length                sin                   
asin                  exp                   log                   single                
asinh                 expm1                 log10                 sinh                  
atan                  ezcontour             log1p                 size                  
atan2                 ezcontourf            log2                  slice                 
atanh                 ezgraph3              logical               smooth3               
bar                   ezmesh                loglog                sort                  
bar3                  ezmeshc               lt                    sprintf               
bar3h                 ezplot                lu                    spy                   
barh                  ezplot3               mat2str               sqrt                  
beta                  ezpolar               max                   stairs                
betaln                ezsurf                mesh                  stem                  
bitand                ezsurfc               meshc                 stem3                 
bitcmp                feather               meshgrid              stream2               
bitor                 fft                   meshz                 stream3               
bitshift              fft2                  min                   streamline            
bitxor                fftn                  minus                 streamparticles       
bsxfun                fill                  mldivide              streamribbon           
cast                  fill3                 mod                   streamslice           
cat                   filter                mrdivide              streamtube            
ceil                  filter2               mtimes                sub2ind               
chol                  find                  ndgrid                subsasgn              
circshift             fix                   ndims                 subsindex             
clabel                floor                 ne                    subsref               
classUnderlying       fplot                 norm                  subvolume             
comet                 fprintf               not                   sum                   
comet3                full                  num2str               surf                  
compass               gamma                 numel                 surfc                 
complex               gammaln               or                    surfl                 
coneplot              gather                pareto                svd                   
conj                  ge                    pcolor                tan                   
contour               gt                    permute               tanh                  
contour3              hist                  pie                   times                 
contourc              horzcat               pie3                  transpose             
contourf              hypot                 plot                  tril                  
contourslice          ifft                  plot3                 trimesh               
conv                  ifft2                 plotmatrix            trisurf               
conv2                 ifftn                 plotyy                triu                  
cos                   imag                  plus                  uint16                
cosh                  image                 polar                 uint32                
cot                   imagesc               power                 uint64                
coth                  ind2sub               prod                  uint8                 
csc                   int16                 qr                    uminus                
csch                  int2str               quiver                uplus                 
ctranspose            int32                 quiver3               vertcat               
cumprod               int64                 rdivide               vissuite              
cumsum                int8                  real                  volumebounds          
curl                  interpstreamspeed     reallog               voronoi               
det                   inv                   realpow               waterfall             
diag                  ipermute              realsqrt              xor                   
diff                  isempty               reducepatch           
disp                  isequal               reducevolume           

Static methods: 

colon                 linspace              rand                  zeros                 
eye                   logspace              randi                 
false                 nan                   randn                 
inf                   ones                  true
```

Note that imfilter seems to be absent.

However imfilter is advertised as gpuArray compatible on its [reference page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using Matlab 2014a ?

Comment: Most probably you are using one of the older versions of MATLAB, when they didn't have `gpuArray` support for `imfilter`. To make it sure, you may type in `help gpuArray/imfilter` and it would show you `gpuArray/imfilter not found.`